# Multiple RegisterClientScriptBlock's

Tags: asp.net

I want to call 3 javascript functions on my .cs file, I tried this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript;
                ClientScriptManager script2 = Page.ClientScript;
                ClientScriptManager script3 = Page.ClientScript;

                script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "centerPopup1()", true);
                script2.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "loadPopup1()", true);
                script3.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "msg1()", true);

            }
        }
```

With no success, nothing happens on my Postbacks, but if I try just calling one of these functions, it works.

Comment: Is the `(IsPostBack)` a typo? You are always using the same identifier for your script blocks (_"key"_)!

Comment: I hope not. I'm quite new to development and asp, I followed the example from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believer you can only Register one StartupScript Block and multiple ClientScriptBlocks (different keys)
Instead of creating multiple; have them next to one another.

Startup : will load in the Form
ClientScript: bottom of page

```
script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "centerPopup1(); 
loadPopUp1();  msg1();", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are always using the same identifier for your script blocks (*"key"*). If i remember corectly the last script-block wins  in this case. So you should provide different keys.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx):

> A client script is uniquely identified by its key and its type.
>   Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one
>   script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page.
>   Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not
>   create a duplicate of the script.

Edit: I assume that you also wanted to register the script only on the initial load and **not** on postbacks. So you should check for `if(!IsPostBack)` instead.

Comment: I just tried unique keys with no success. I thought maybe it was something in my JS, so I decided to just call in 2 simple alert functions, none of them showed up. Tried again just calling one of them, works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegisterStartupScript instead of RegisterClientScriptBlock. With RegisterClientScriptBlock, your script calls may be executed before the rest of the page loads. If the components that you are trying to reference have not yet loaded the calls will fail.

Also, you'll have to enclose your javascript code in script tags.

See [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Type, String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y).